# SQL counting numbers of unique values in a column and doing a sum of that info

Tags: sql, count, sum

I am trying to make a sum of the count of different values.

Here's an example :

```js
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
d
d
d
d
e
e
e
e
```

The output would be :

```
5
```

Because there's 5 different values in that column.

Comment: I tryed something like this but with no succes 

SELECT SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT value)) AS numberOfUniqueValues
FROM table

Answer (score 3):

Perform a `Distinct Count` which should give you the `count` of `distinct` values in a column and no need to do `sum` here

```
select count(distinct colname) 
from yourtable
```

Comment: That doesnt count how much of unique values i've got.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and giving some good tought and testing here's the correct query :

SELECT SUM(uniqueValues) FROM (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT values) as uniqueValues FROM tablename GROUP BY values)